# How to publish my ruby gem to my own repository?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, rake-task

I have written a `ruby gem` and I would like to have a rake task for publishing the gem to my **own `GemInABox` repository** : `http://my-gem-repo.com`.

What is the simplest way of achieving this goal?

Also, I would like to prevent the default publishing to `Rubygems.org`.

Comment: http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind writing a full answer and I will accept it?

Comment: which gem repo are you using, `GemInABox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Information on hosting your own gem can be found at http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/

Setup the server according to that site and the README on https://github.com/cwninja/geminabox

To release your gem:

```
gem build my_ruby_gem.gemspec
#push all versions to the gem server
gem inabox
```

The first time you run gem inabox, you will configure the destination.

For rake tasks, you could put this Rakefile in your gem source:

```
#!/usr/bin/env rake
desc "build the gem"
task :build do
  system("gem build *.gemspec")
end

desc "push the gem to the gem inabox server"
task :release do
  system("gem inabox")
end

desc "build and release the gem"
task :build_and_release => [:build,:release]
```

The system calls are definitely hacks, but they are a simple way to make it work.   Better rake tasks are requested in:
https://github.com/cwninja/geminabox/issues/59